# Cron does not detect $USER when running shell script

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to create a simple resource logging script on Linux Mint 20.3. The script `minute_log.sh` is expected to analyze the home directory size and log it into a file every minute. Assume `USER=itsme`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_PATH="/home/${USER}"
LOG_PATH="${TARGET_PATH}/log"
DATE_OUT=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
LOGFILE="${LOG_PATH}/metrics_${DATE_OUT}.log"

du -sh $TARGET_PATH > $LOGFILE
```

I run the script normally and works as expected, giving the output `14G /home/itsme` in the specified `$LOGFILE`. Then, I move it to `~/.local/bin` and I set up my crontab as follows using `crontab -e`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash

* * * * * /home/itsme/.local/bin/minute_log.sh
```

Using this setup, I noticed that there are no files logged into `$LOGFILE`. Upon checking the `cron` service log using `systemctl` (the command is `systemctl status cron.service`), I noticed that it tried to run the following:

```
CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
        ├─   663 /usr/sbin/cron -f
        ├─128975 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
        ├─128976 /bin/bash /home/itsme/.local/bin/minute_log.sh
        ├─128982 /bin/bash /home/itsme/.local/bin/minute_log.sh
        └─128983 du -sh /home/
```

Notice that `$USER` is considered empty when passed to `du` command. Then when it tries to log to `/home//log/`, it failed because of permission restrictions and the folder does not exist there and cannot be created. Hence, the expected log path of `/home/itsme/log/` never populated.

However, if I change `$TARGET_PATH` to the following:

```sh
TARGET_PATH="$HOME"
```

It works without problem and successfully logs the file to to `$LOGFILE`.

Can anyone explain why this might happen on the `cron` side?

Comment: `cron` gets a very limited repertoire of environment variables. Is there a reason you are not using `$HOME`, or simply a relative file path? `cron` jobs will always start in the owner's home directory.

Comment: @tripleee I would like `$TARGET_PATH` to be modifiable to point at arbitrary path. Also, I haven't thought of using "relative to home" path in `cron`. Probably I will try that.

Comment: Probably a better design altogether is to pass the destination file as a command-line argument, or simply have the script print to standard error and have the `cron` invocation redrect it to a convenient location.

Comment: @tripleee The problem is that the destination/output file name changes every minute and I want to put them all in a directory. But if you mean the destination _directory_ as an argument, then that might work.